# Find a conformal map from the unit disc minus a disc in its interior to the unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find a conformal map from the unit disc minus the disc, $|z+\frac{1}{2}|<\frac{1}{2}$, onto the unit disc. I've been playing around with linear fractional transformations, but I haven't been able to cook up anything useful yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anything even remotely holomorphic won't work, and I have little experience with non-holomorphic conformal maps

Comment: But conformal maps are bijective holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{z+1}-\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$$

First $(z+1)^{-1}$ maps to the strip $\tfrac12 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < 1$. Then $\pi \,(z-\tfrac34)$ maps to the strip $-\pi/4 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < \pi/4$. Then $\tan(z)$ maps to the disc.